# Graphics performance is too slow on ubuntu

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

The only reason that made me switch to windows is games. If I can play league of legends or dota 2 on ubuntu, I will never install windows again, I think.

I have successfully installed dota 2 via steam on my ubuntu 16.04. However the graphics performance is really bad, even the lowest graphics configurations and even with a competitive hardware:

- NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960M,
- Intel i7 5700HQ 2.7GHz processors
- 8GB of system RAM

I assumed maybe the graphics driver causing this issue. I have checked the default graphics driver and nouveau driver is being used. I have removed and install the actual nvidia driver from repository (nvidia-361), checked again, my default driver is now nvidia.

I tested my graphics performance after I made the changes abowe. But the test showed me that my changes are futile. I have used the Unigine benchmark I would like [here](https://unigine.com/). Graphics configurations in test was normal, means I didn't crank up to extreme tessellation, anti-aliasing and extreme texture quality etc.

I don't know what else to do from here. I would really like to find a way how to get better results from the test, 20-25 FPS is enough with normal graphics configuration. Here is some commands and their outputs:

```
bora@bora-PC:~/Desktop/Unigine_Heaven-4.0$ sudo lshw -c video
[sudo] password for bora: 
*-display               
   description: 3D controller
   product: GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M]
   vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: a2
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
   resources: irq:40 memory:9a000000-9affffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff memory:c0000000-c1ffffff ioport:4000(size=128) memory:9b000000-9b07ffff
*-display
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 0a
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
   resources: irq:35 memory:99000000-99ffffff memory:a0000000-afffffff ioport:5000(size=64)
```

And:

```
bora@bora-PC:~/Desktop/Unigine_Heaven-4.0$ sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
== cpu-microcode.py ==
driver   : intel-microcode - distro non-free

== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd0000139Bsv00000000sd00000000bc03sc02i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M]
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
driver   : nvidia-361 - distro non-free recommended
```